# Best practices of using asp.net web api authentication

Tags: android, api, forms-authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating Asp.net web api project, which is needed for an android application for getting responses from the server.

I'm going to use FormsAuthentication for authentication. What should I return from my Login method? The app can do the next request after some hours from login. Should android app save username/password and return it back to the API with each request? Or should I return Authentication cookie?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you like to use `forms-authentication` because if you are going for mobile development, it's better to use OAuth/ token based authentication.

Comment: @su8898, No. The question mostly is this. What is better and the ways how should I use it.